# How to hide navigation bar while scrolling the table view which is inside the collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a view controller which contains a collection view. Inside the collection view I have a table view. Whenever I scroll the table view the navigation bar should hide.

1. view controller
2. collection view --- collection view cell
3. table view ---- table view cell

How to hide the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create delegate methods on the collectionViewCell which has UITableView

```
@objc protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate {
  func didScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) 
  func didEndDecelerating()
  func didEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.delegate.didScroll(scrollView)
}
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    self.delegate.didEndDragging(scrollView)
}
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.delegate.didEndDecelerating()
}
```

and implement these delegate methods on the ViewController which has UICollectionView to hide navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrollview delegate method to hide and show navigation bar. 
check below methods

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if decelerate == false {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
}
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: its getting error. "Value of type 'CustomCollectionViewCell' has no member 'navigationController'" because the tableview is present inside the collectionview. so all the tabelview delegates and datasource methods are written inside the custom collectionview cell. including scrollviewdidscroll method.

Comment: implement these delegate methods on the ViewController which has UICollectionView to hide navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

use observer in these methods to achieve your goal

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: 
    NSNotification.Name("ScrollStart"), object: nil)
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, 
    willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: 
    NSNotification.Name("ScrollEnd"), object: nil)
}
```

and now where you want to hide the navigation bar add in that controller's view didload() the folowing code

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
     #selector(self.hideNavigationMethod), name: 
 NSNotification.Name("ScrollStart"), object: nil)
```

similarly for showing the navigation bar

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
     #selector(self.showNavigationMethod), name: 
NSNotification.Name("ScrollEnd"), object: nil)
```

now implement methods hideNavigationMethod() and showNavigationMethod()